# My view displays raw blade code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel and using ver 5.5. I have a simple view and when I run the code, instead of showing the rendered version, I see the Blade commands.

This is the view code:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>{{ $title }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                {!!  \App\Combine\BaseCombine::tableHeader($collection) !!}
                {!!  \App\Combine\BaseCombine::tableData($collection) !!}
                {!!  \App\Combine\BaseCombine::tableFooter($collection) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('transaction.index') }}"> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Here is the code in the controller that executes the view:

```
return view('general.genericTable',
       [
            'title'         => __FUNCTION__,
            'transactionID' => $transactionsID,
            'type'          => $type,
            'collection'    => TransactionCombine::agents($transactionsID, $type),
        ]
    );
```

This is what I see when I execute the code:

```
@section('content')

{{ $title }}

{!! \App\Combine\BaseCombine::tableHeader($collection) !!} {!! \App\Combine\BaseCombine::tableData($collection) !!} {!! \App\Combine\BaseCombine::tableFooter($collection) !!}
Back

@endsection
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: maybe the problem is in your config/app.php, does `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class` exist in the `providers` array ?

Comment: view filename extension **.blade.php**

Comment: Yes, of course, it was the file name. Alas, I do not yet think in Larvel as yet and even the simplest thing can seem a wide abyss. Thank you @Ben